# Play sound file in a web-page in the background

Tags: html, firefox

I want to play a sound file on my web-page in the back-ground(don't want Media player UI to appear), my web-site will run on Fire-Fox, i used the Embed element and set the Hidden attribute to be true `<embed name="myMusic" src="Masgon.mp3" type="audio/midi"
 autostart="false" Hidden="true" loop="true"></embed>`
 the problem is that no sound is played unless i removed the hidden attribute on this case the sound file is played and the media player UI appears but i don't want that.

Comment: The file is of type audio/mp3 while the type attribute has a value of "audio/midi". midi files have .mid or .midi extensions.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<audio src="/music/good_enough.mp3">
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.     </p>
</audio>
```

and if you want the controls

```
<audio src="/music/good_enough.mp3" controls>
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

and also using embed

```
<embed src="/music/good_enough.mp3" width="180" height="90" loop="false" autostart="false" hidden="true" />
```

Comment: See this for Firefox issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529645/how-to-add-background-music-to-a-web-page . Embed should work but if not use Object

Comment: This doesnt answer the problem "unless i removed the hidden attribute" solution is the use width=0 and height=0

Answer (score 12):

```
<audio src="/music/good_enough.mp3" autoplay>
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.     </p>
<embed src="/music/good_enough.mp3" width="180" height="90" hidden="true" />
</audio>
```

Works for me just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Though this might be too late to comment but here's the working code for problems such as yours.

```
<div id="player">
    <audio autoplay hidden>
     <source src="link/to/file/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                If you're reading this, audio isn't supported. 
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove `controls` from your code and will be perfect

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić True! There's no point in setting the `controls` if the audio is `hidden` (and on `autoplay` ).

Answer (score 3):

```
<audio controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="path/your_song.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <embed src="path/your_song.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"> 
</audio>
```

[ps. replace the "path/your_song.mp3" with the folder and the song title eg. "music/samplemusic.mp3" or "media/bgmusic.mp3" etc.

Comment: this is best for autoplay, other methods cause error "play() failed because the user didn’t interact with the document "

Answer (score 1):

With me the problem was solved by removing the `type` attribute:

```
<embed name="myMusic" loop="true" hidden="true" src="Music.mp3"></embed>
```

Cerntainly not the cleanest way.

If you're using HTML5:
MP3 isn't supported by Firefox. Wav and Ogg are though.
Here you can find an overview of which browser support which type of audio:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: I tried it with a .wave file but it doesn't work, the same scenario above

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show controls then try this code

```
<audio  autoplay>
 <source src="song.ogg"  type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it just normal:

```
<audio src="sus.mp3">
    <script>alert("Your browser doesn't support the Audio tag!")</script>
</audio>`
```

if you want it to automatically start on load: (Not supported by chrome)

```
<audio src="sus.mp3" autostart="true">
    <script>alert("Your browser doesn't support the Audio tag!")</script>
</audio>
```

if you want the controls

```
<audio src="sus.mp3" autostart="true" controls>
    <script>alert("Your browser doesn't support the Audio tag!")</script>
</audio>
```