# convert play framework route to java URL class (used to initialize java.net.URL class)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to play song in page when it opening. (I know It's a bad idea but I want to say Happy Birthday to my cousins :D ) for that I need to convert play framework routes to java.net.URL class. I tried these line of code but all of them gave me NULL pointer

```
URL url = app.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( 
    "../../public/sounds/9-Baroon.wav");

URL url = app.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
    controllers.routes.Assets.at("sounds/9-Baroon.wav").absoluteURL(request()));

URL url = app.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( 
    controllers.routes.Assets.at("sounds/9-Baroon.wav");
```

how can I get that music file?

### Some word

I'm stupid. I think I had to use controller for playing sound but this must done in views. I don't remove this question because anyone make that mistake find his/her mistake sooner.

Comment: What you gonna do with URL entity once converted?

Comment: play a sound : `AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);` my problem is that url is null in this statement

Comment: Are you going to play the sound on a webpage? So the code `AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);` will run in Java Applet or where? How you gonna pass url object from Play Framework (server-side) to Java Applet?

Comment: I want to play song in web page. isn't it possible in this way ? shame on me !!!!

Comment: Check http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13402388/972676 . Play framework has nothing to do with it.

Comment: thanks. write this as an answer I will check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Play Framework. You want to play sound on the webpage directly from HTML (or with some Javascript).

So you don't need Java for it (though your still can serve your `.wav` file from Play Framework as static asset).

Check these links: [w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp](http://w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) or [stackoverflow.com/a/13402388/972676](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402388/972676).

Comment: thanks bro. don't tell any one I made that mistake :D