# HTML adding a background music that will not stop or start from the beginning when ever i go to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I'm making a simple website, my home section is as follows, there's also the other sections which are sorta similar, but my question is that I want a background music to play without stopping or restarting whenever I go to "about", "meeting" and what not.

ps: i'm using notepad++

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="About.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Meeting.html">Meeting</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Personality.html">Personailty</a>
  </li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="PatchingUp.html">Patching Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p class="paragraph1">Hello there!</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play sound file in a web-page in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402336/play-sound-file-in-a-web-page-in-the-background)

Comment: the music control must be part of your HTML page. Therefore, if you request a new HTML page, inevitably it refreshes everything, including stopping any media playback. Just as if you went to another site entirely. The browser doesn't really distinguish between going from one page to another in the same site, and one page to another in a different site. So your playback will stop every time, because a whole new page is loaded and the previous one discarded.

Comment: to get round this, you could consider redesigning your site as a single page, with the parts that are currently in different HTML files just being sections of a single page which are shown/hidden using javascript when the user clicks on the menu items. Or you could even load the content on-demand via ajax. Lots of sites already follow this kind of design model. This way, you will never actually request a full page load, and so playback of your media can continue un-interrupted while the user browses all your content areas.