# Playing audio in background in PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html, html5-audio

I am working on a music site (http://goodhub.000webhostapp.com) and I need help playing the music in the background.

Comment: that's nice, so what's the question?

Comment: (That’s not my downvote, by the way …). This is not a PHP question. HTML5 includes the `audio` element which will do the job: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio. If you want some additional control, that will require JavaScript.

Comment: nogad I was asking if there is a way to play audio without the controls.
Manngo I stated PHP because the entire site is in PHP.

Comment: @Softy The answer is still to use the HTML `audio` element, so you won’t need PHP code. I will ellaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **audio** tag or an **embed** tag.

Similar query has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402388/2389101

Comment: Thanks. Will try:)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 includes the `audio` element, which will allow you to include an audio file.

A simple version of the format of `audio` is:

```
<audio src="…" autoplay muted loop controls>
```

Apart from the `src`, the attributes are all optional. When used they have the following meanings:

- `muted`: start silent
- `autoplay`: start when page is loaded
- `loop`: repeat
- `controls`: show control buttons

This will work in all modern browsers, which *excludes* legacy versions of IE.