# Play audio in background on the same page

Tags: html, css

We are developing an application to manage sound in stores (emergency, promotions, playlists, ...) based on IP network speakers.

Currently we are having trouble to find a solution to play a sound on the speaker with IP x.x.x.x by clicking the "play" button on a web page.

The below setup works (the sound plays), but it always opens a new tab in our browser. We would like play the sound in a "hidden" way (doesn't open up a separate tab/window/whatever) but plays in the background of the existing page.
Same applies for our "stop" button (this also opens in a separate tab)

This is the html code we're using (I removed all icons, etc...)

---

```
<tr>
    <td>Fire evacuation</td>
    <td><div class= "tag-emergency"><i class="fas fa-fire"></i> Emergency</div></td>
    <td><a href="http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/playclip.cgi?clip=3" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding play"><i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i></a></td>
    <td><a href="http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/mediaclip.cgi?action=stop" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding stop"><i class="fas fa-stop fa-fw"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
```

Someone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Nico

Comment: forget the cgi scripts, stick with html5 spec https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697257/3933927

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with AJAX. It should look something like this for one Button:

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonClass").onclick = function(e) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/playclip.cgi?clip=3",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
```

and the HTML:

```
 <td><a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding play yourButtonClass"><i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Axis also today (vendor network speaker):

The new tab is being opened due to the usage of a VAPIX command. These always open in a new tab.

So can we have a workaround with your Ajax approach you think?

Thanks,

Nico