# add the background music on website by using iframe

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to add the code into body tag but it doesn't work.

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" src="here.mp3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402336/play-sound-file-in-a-web-page-in-the-background ) will help you in what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can use embed tag for this like below

```
<embed src="yourMusic.mp3">
```

OR

```
<audio src="yourMusic.mp3">
```

Also, you can check more options here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp