# How to send a audio file to a view using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I have a `.mp3` file in my content folder on the server side. How can I return it to a view (client side) as a action result?

Comment: Do you want to return it to the view as download file? Or you want it to be returned as a link so that the audio player on your front end can play?

Comment: Hi! I want to play in background a sound on client side, but this sound is located in my web site server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play sound file in a web-page in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402336/play-sound-file-in-a-web-page-in-the-background)

Comment: Nice! this answer help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult Play()
    {
        string audio = Server.MapPath("~") + @"Content\Uploads\audio.wav";
        if (audio != null && audio != "")
        {
            try
            {
                using (SoundPlayer SPlayer = new SoundPlayer(audio))
                {
                    SPlayer.PlaySync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Source != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Source);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```