# Playing MP3 in background of webpage

Tags: html, audio, mp3, playback

I'm creating this fun little website and I want NyanCat.mp3 to play as soon as the user enters the website and I do not want the controls to be shown.Unfortunately with the code I've got, it only works if the user has controls. I also want it to loop.

Without Controls - Does not work

```
<audio loop="loop">
<source src="NyanCat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

With Controls - Does work

```
<audio loop="loop" controls="controls">
<source src="NyanCat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: 1998 called: they'd like their bad website design back.

Comment: Oh please :P I'm not even a web developer, Python ftw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the controls to be shown, delete the `controls` atribute, but add the `autoplay` atribute instead:

```
<audio loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="NyanCat.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Anyway, it's always a good idea to give the user the control to play/stop the music.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Use jQuery to your job. call on page load function. Here is code [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529645/how-to-add-background-music-to-a-web-page)

**Option 2**

Use a external plugin to your job.  Here is a [Wordpress plugin](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/)

**Option 3**

The MSDN way of doing it. Refer this [Play audio without audio tag visibility](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5aaca492-c1f7-44ae-ad81-2895e3618ca6/play-audio-without-a-visible-audio-tag?forum=winappswithhtml5)

Hope this helps :)